# Docker-Compose too many levels of symlinks with NFS

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nfs

I am trying to volume mount an nfs share but I am running into some issues with that. When I run a regular docker command such as:

```
docker run -i -t privileged=true -v /mnt/bluearc:/mnt/bluarc -v /net:/net ubuntu bash
```

I have my desired drive mounted at `/mnt/bluearc`. However, if I run it with docker-compose:

```
test_ser:
  container_name: test_ser
  hostname: test_ser
  image: ubuntu
  restart: always
  working_dir: /repo/drop_zone_dub
  volumes_from:
    - nerve_repo_data
  volumes:
    - /mnt/bluearc:/mnt/bluearc
    - /net:/net
  privileged: true
  command: bash
```

When I try to access the directories I get the following error:

`Too many levels of symbolic links`

What is compose doing differently that would cause this?

Comment: Any chance your `nerve_repo_data` volume also contain the same volumes?

Comment: No, it just contains the immediate repository, but good idea

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and find a hidden docker parameter here:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24303

```
-v /nfs:/nfs:shared
```

It works for me so far.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is related to Docker and Automounting.  See https://serverfault.com/questions/640895/why-do-some-host-volumes-in-docker-containers-give-the-error-too-many-levels-of
It seems to just be something Docker can't do.

Answer (score 0):

we usually use:

`-v /nfs:/nfs:slave`

Which we found to work better with autofs/auto-mounter.

Comment: where exactly do you put this command? Inside docker-compose.yml? or just behind docker-compose up ? cause that command is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

In this thread, I found a solution
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5763

Reverting to an older version of `docker-desktop` via `chocolately` helped me.

```
choco uninstall docker-desktop
choco install docker-desktop --version=2.1.0.5 --allow-downgrade
```

This problem apparently is a problem with the linux kernel used by windows.